# How to create a stretched symbology with labels for each 1 meter in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology

Can anybody help me with this problem. I want to create a stretched symbology with hard colour breaks and label for each 1 metre in ArcMap.

[image: The symbology I want to create]

I know how to create a symbology with hard colour breaks and min max label values.

[image: Hard breaks]

And I also know how to create a symbology with graduated colour and label values for each 1 metre.

[image: Label for each 1 metre]

But how do I make a symbology with hard colour breaks and also label values for each 1 metre?

Comment: How about using Classified symbology instead? Or is there a specific reason to use Stretched?

Comment: If I use classified the symbology will only have a 1 metre division. I need a more graduated division. And if I   choose 0,25 m division I will get about 100 labels which will take up to much space

Comment: As much as I hate resorting to this workaround, what about two instances of the feature: one with hard color breaks for the data, one with graduated color and 1m label values for the legend?

Comment: This would unfortunately not create the needed legend. I could get the different labels from advanced labeling. But if I place the legend with max/min values on top of the other legend the color ramp will not match up since this is much shorter than the other one, see above pictures. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly. You want your data to display with hard color breaks every 0.25m and have a stretched legend with labels every 1.0m?

Comment: @khafen, no not quite. I want a stretched symbology with Algorithmic Color Ramp (picture 2)  and labels for a specific interval (picture 3). The result I want is shown in my first picture. The specific interval where I want hard color breaks does not matter in regards to a general solution for creating hard color breaks and labels for a specific interval with ArcMap